# Displaying custom post-types in a Fancybox div and then linking to them

Tags: jquery

How could I go about this…

I have a portfolio page, created using custom post-types, and on the portfolio page I have a number of thumbnails which I would like to link to each project I add through a custom post-type. Hope this part makes sense?

Where it gets tricky, I want each of these thumbnails to make use of the Fancybox plugin so that when a user clicks on a thumbnail it brings up a div container with all of the content I from that particular project's post. Lost me yet?

Its a bit difficult to explain, but hopefully someone out there will know what I mean and suggest how I can cleverly make the page grab all of the content within that thumbnail's post and display it with the Fancybox 'pop out'.

The reason for this is simply because I have a lot of projects I want to display, and if I were to have a file which included pop up div with content for each project, the file would be huge! And I just don't think its a great way to manage things.

Thanks,

Ash

Answer (score 1):

If popup div is out of the question since you have a lot of projects on a page then another option is to use ajax to grab the project content which shouldn't be too hard. and an even simpler solution would be to use jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

first wrap you thumbnails with a link to the project page:

```
<a class="project_thumb" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> ... thumbnail here </a>
```

then add this js code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.project_thumb').live('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            url = url + ' #portfolioProject';
            $('#content').load(url, function(data, stat, req){
                $(this).fancybox();
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

and just change `#content` to the id of the content container of your single project view.

Comment: I just had a go at this, but when I implement it to the site, doesn't seem to be solving the problem. [link]http://www.ashleymosuro.com/newsite/portfolio

This is the page I'm trying to use it on. For some reason it seems to include the entire page into the fancybox whereas I only want a section of the page to be displayed. Plus, my close button seems to be playing up. Any suggestions?

Comment: your code is looking for the wrong container , in your JS code change `portfolioProject` to `mainContent` to fix it. and let me know.

Comment: A bit confused by that, because I have a div named portfolioProject which contains all of the elements I want to display within the fancy box. I have tried changing it to mainContent but still it displays the entire page within the fancybox, check the link again to see what I mean

Comment: I see what you mean, i've updated the answer with a fixed code. i basically added the selector of the element to be returned. let me know

Comment: Just had a go at that too, no luck! [link]http://ashleymosuro.com/newsite/portfolio/

Comment: I'm getting this error from Firebug too:

jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function

And for some reason, the second thumbnail does not appear to work, even though it is using the same code as the first. Thanks for the help so far, hopefully we'll get there!

Comment: Ok I've basically found a way around this, but to be honest its not exactly practical. I could simply remove all of the elements within the single-portfolio.php page that I do not want to appear, just leaving the details about that particular portfolio item. But obviously this would mean that If I ever wanted to create a page for that portfolio item, it would be broken because there will be no structure around the details. You can see what I have done by checking the link again, but like I said, this is not really the way I want to do it.

Comment: Ok I've got another idea, follow my last comment and create an hidden div (`style="display: none;"`) with the ID of content (`id="content"`), then change `$(this).fancybox();` to  `$("#content").fancybox();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bainternet, but just want to be clear on your instructions. I have created a hidden div with the id of 'content', but where exactly should I place this div? On the single-portfolio.php or portfolio.php file? And should I be wrapping the content I want to display within this div, or just keep the div empty. Its probably worth checking the link once again just in case I have changed anything since your reply.

Comment: keep it empty and simply add it to your portfolio.php (the one with the thumbnails who show the fancyboxy)

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything, the fancybox still loads the entire single-portfolio.php page. Any ideas? I'm not too great with Jquery (though I generally understand how to implement it and modify) so I'm a bit lost..

Comment: Any ideas Bainternet? A bit stuck with this after trying a few ways...

Comment: The problem is, how do you tell jquery to load the div from the permalink? Is there some sort of syntax that allows you to use the get_permalink call within jquery. Otherwise I can't see how you are going to be able to make this work with the posts. Really scratching my head with this one if anyone could help...

Comment: @Bainternet Have a look at this link [http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/e7ddc7d05098705e/0d6561cd7b19d30c?lnk=gst&q=wordpress+ajax#0d6561cd7b19d30c]

Seems like this guy had the same problem, however I'm a bit confused with his jquery. `/dir/dir2/?page=info ` - what exactly does that directory do? Are they his own folders or is this some sort of location to grab the page's URL? Also, could I be having problems because my post-type and page are both called Portfolio?