# Displaying div from custom-post-type in Fancy Box

Tags: jquery

First of all, I have posted a very similar question here:

[Displaying custom post-types in a Fancybox div and then linking to them](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19124/displaying-custom-post-types-in-a-fancybox-div-and-then-linking-to-them)

However, after being unable to find a solution I have taken a different approach and created a template page with just the portfolioProject div and not included the other elements such as header and footer. So now on this page( [click here](http://www.ashleymosuro.com/newsite/portfolio)) when I click on one of the thumbnails it opens up the fancybox div but I have a few issues:

1. The close button doesn't appear
   to work
2. The second thumbnail doesn't
   appear to work but the first does
3. I don't want the scrollbar to show,
   and I have tried using the `option
   scrollbar : 'no'` but it does not
   seem to work

Any help on this would be great! Thanks,

Ash

Answer (score 1):

This follow-up no longer seems to fit here in WordPress Answers, but here's what I think:

1. Close button works fine for me on all thumbnails (Chrome 16 on Mac);
2. The thumbnails which did not work need to be `<a class="fancybox"...`, which they weren't;
3. You can probably try a CSS-only alternative for hiding scrollbars, which is `overflow: hidden`; since your using iframe fancyboxes, you might want to precede the element which you want to suppress scrollbars with `#fancybox-wrap` or `#fancy_outer` or something on those lines, so you can remove those scrollbars only when the page is rendered inside a fancybox;

Answer (score 0):

Im using Chrome 12 on Mac.

1. The close button works for me but clicking outside the box does not close.
2. All the thumbnails work for me.
3. I believe the correct syntax would be `scrolling: no` ([Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/api))

I notice you are using the Fancybox for Wordpress plugin, most of the options should be able to set in the admin panel.